# symfony2 many-to-many form checkbox

Tags: forms, symfony, many-to-many

I have in symfony created 2 entities: User and Role in many-to-many relationship. That means every user can have more roles and roles can be set to many users.

**User class:**

```
  /**
   * @ORM\Entity
   * @ORM\Table(name="JEP_User")
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Chrchel\JepBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
   */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface {

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="username",type="string",length=100,unique=true)
 */
private $username;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
 *
 */
protected $roles;

//....
}
```

**Role class:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="JEP_Role")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
 class Role implements RoleInterface {

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

  /** @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30) */
protected $name;

 /** @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true) */
protected $role;

 /** @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles") */
protected $users;
 //...
 }
```

I cant figure how to compose query builder in Symfony2 to list all roles that exists and add it to the end of UserForm where can be selected (as checkboxes) roles granted to the user.
I tried to use collection like this in UserType

```
->add('roles', 'collection',array('label' => 'Role', 'required' => false,'type'=> new RoleType()))
```

The best I get from symfony are rows with textboxes with selected names of roles. But this is not, what I need.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've used **entity type** instead of collection. I thing collection is mainly used to actually **create** a `Role` object and assign it to `User`.

If you want to just list all existing roles and be able to select and assign it to the user then:

```
->add('roles', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Role',
    'property'     => 'name',
    'multiple'     => true
));
```

**EDIT**: this will render the widget as a multiple `<select>`, refer to [entity type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) to render as checkbox list.

Comment: set the `expanded` option to `true` to have a checkbox list. And You need to implement the `__toString()` method on `Role` model (used to display the label next to each checkbox.

Comment: I found I had to add another method to the User entity to return roles as a Collection instead of as an array - getRolesAsCollection.

Comment: And how do you call this specific `getRolesAsCollection` and where?

Answer (score 9):

## Symfony3:

In case anyone is using **Symfony3**:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

->add('roles', EntityType::class, array( // <-- EntityType::class is unique to Symfony3
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Role',
    'choice_label' => 'name', // <-- choice_label is unique to Symfony3
    'multiple' => true
))
```

Comment: I have the exact same format as above (Symfony 3: answer 4). The field represented by 'roles' has been setup as ManyToMany. I have it setup using  ArrayCollection() (also tried without). Either way I get an error and can't for the life of me figure it out. Would love some feedback. Without ArrayCollection: ERROR = "Unable to transform value for property path "users": Expected a Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object."

Answer (score 7):

@user1041880: If you use the symfony security functions (which needs the roles of th euser as an array), you can do it like this:

```
->add('rolesAsCollection', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Role',
    'property'     => 'name',
    'multiple'     => true
));
```

And in your user class:

```
public function getRolesAsCollection()
{
    return $this->roles;
}
```