# Generate symfony2 form with one-to-many-to-one entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm struggling with a symfony2 form. Basically i would like to manage User's preference to receive (or not) an email for each type of action an User could do.

Here my schema :
User (extending FOSUB)

EmailUserPreference

```php
class EmailUserPreference {

public function __construct(User $user, \Adibox\Bundle\ActionBundle\Entity\ActionType $actionType) {
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->actionType = $actionType;
    $this->activated = true;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */

protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Adibox\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="id")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Adibox\Bundle\ActionBundle\Entity\ActionType", inversedBy="id")
 */
private $actionType;

/**
 * @ORM\Column activated(type="boolean")
 */
private $activated;
/*getters / setters ... */
}
```

ActionType

```php
class ActionType
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $value
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $value;
/* and some others */
}
```

Here, i build my form EmailUserPreferenceType :

```php
class EmailUserPreferenceType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ->add('emailPreference', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AdiboxActionBundle:ActionType',
                'property' => 'value',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function(\Adibox\Bundle\ActionBundle\Entity\ActionTypeRepository $er) {
                    return $er->getAllActionsWithPreferences();
                }
            ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'emailUserPreference';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
        return array('data_class' => 'Adibox\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\EmailUserPreference');
    }

}
```

And finally the ActionTypeRepository with the function called in the FormType :

```php
class ActionTypeRepository extends EntityRepository {

public function getAllActionsWithPreferences() {
    $arrayActionWithPreferences = array(
        'share',
        'refuse',
        'validate',
        'validatePayment',
        'createPayment',
        'estimateChangeState',
        'comment',
        'createRepetition',
        'display',
        'DAFLate',
    );
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->where($qb->expr()->in('a.value', $arrayActionWithPreferences));
    return $qb;
    }

}
```

At this point, I thought it was OK : i got a good rendering, with the right form. But in fact, each checkbox has the same form name than the other. In other words each time the form is submitted, it only send in post a `$builderemailUserPreference[emailUserPreference][]` data. Obviously, it does not work as i expected.

I show these posts 
http://sf.khepin.com/2011/08/basic-usage-of-the-symfony2-collectiontype-form-field/
Here he's using a widget Collection. I'm not sure i should use it or entity (like i did). But what i can read from http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html, it seems more like an embedding form than an entity.

And finally i saw this : [symfony2 many-to-many form checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719094/symfony2-many-to-many-form-checkbox)
This one is using (indeed) Collection and many-to-many relations. I read somewhere (can't find the link anymore) that i can't use it since i need to add some attributes to the relation (in this case `bool activated`). I'm pretty sure the solution is near the link above, but can't find the good way to reach it.

Thank you in advance.

Any advice on what i'm doing wrong or if i should use Collections instead of Entity would be appreciated.