# Symfony2 many-to-many checkboxes

Tags: php, symfony, checkbox, doctrine

I know that question answered a lot of times but i dont understand where is my problem.
So I have simple many-to-many relations:

```
class Item
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */

private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Store", inversedBy="items", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="itemlist",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="item", referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="store", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $stores;
}
```

And Store entity:

```
/**
 * Store
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Store
{   
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="stores", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $items;
}
```

And I want to assign items to stores via checkboxes.

So generate ItemType:

```
class ItemType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $entityManager = $options['em'];

        $builder
            //...
            ->add('stores', 'entity', array('class' => 'FoodBundle:Store', 'property' => 'title','multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true))
            ;
    }
```

And problems starts here.

First of all I'm getting all checkboxes checked, but `itemlist` relation table is empty.

Second I'm getting in this page errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: targetToSourceKeyColumns in \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister.php on line 1773

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister.php on line 1773
```

And finally I can't manage relations via checkboxes and getting:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\foodserv\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 605 and defined
```

I think there is problem in mapping, but this solution fully copied from this [symfony2 many-to-many form checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719094/symfony2-many-to-many-form-checkbox)

UPD: Store setters in Item entity

```
   /**
     * Add store
     *
     * @param \FoodServiceBundle\Entity\Store $store
     *
     * @return Item
     */
    public function addStore(\FoodServiceBundle\Entity\Store $store)
    {
        $this->stores[] = $store;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove store
     *
     * @param \FoodServiceBundle\Entity\Store $store
     */
    public function removeStore(\FoodServiceBundle\Entity\Store $store)
    {
        $this->stores->removeElement($store);
    }

    /**
     * Get stores
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getStores()
    {
        return $this->stores;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your stores setter in your Item entity?

Comment: try without the "JoinTable" part

Comment: @Marcel Burkhard Unbelievable but it works! I'm realy happy) Thanks a lot! Can you explain what is wrong in my solution?

Comment: @Asgu I added my comment as an answer and explained why it works now. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with annotation-mapping to tell you where you went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `@ORM\JoinTable` from your Item entity like so:

```
class Item
{
    //..
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Store", inversedBy="items", cascade="persist"})
     */
    private $stores;
}
```

Doctrine provides sensible default values for the join tables, and you override those with something that doesn't work. By removing `@ORM\JoinTable` it should work again.

Unfortunately I never use the annotation mapping and can't tell you where exactly the error was.

Here is how to use `@ORM\JoinTable` if you need non-default table or column names: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing